# There is an error in XML document (0, 0) during deserialization

Tags: c#, wpf, xmlserializer

i have the following code to for xml serialization.

```
    public class FormSaving
    {
        private string major;

        public string Majorversion
        {
            get;

            set;

        }
    }



    private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string savepath;
        SaveFileDialog DialogSave = new SaveFileDialog();
        // Default file extension
        DialogSave.DefaultExt = "txt";
        // Available file extensions
        DialogSave.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        // Adds a extension if the user does not
        DialogSave.AddExtension = true;
        // Restores the selected directory, next time
        DialogSave.RestoreDirectory = true;
        // Dialog title
        DialogSave.Title = "Where do you want to save the file?";
        // Startup directory
        DialogSave.InitialDirectory = @"C:/";
        DialogSave.ShowDialog();
        savepath = DialogSave.FileName;
        DialogSave.Dispose();
        DialogSave = null;

        FormSaving abc = new FormSaving();
        abc.Majorversion = MajorversionresultLabel.Content.ToString();
        using (Stream savestream = new FileStream(savepath, FileMode.Create))
        {

                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
                serializer.Serialize(savestream, abc);
        }



    }


    private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        Stream checkStream = null;
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog DialogLoad = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
        DialogLoad.Multiselect = false;
        DialogLoad.Filter = "XML file (*.xml)|*.xml|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if ((bool)DialogLoad.ShowDialog())
        {
            try
            {
                if ((checkStream = DialogLoad.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    loadpath = DialogLoad.FileName;
                    checkStream.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Problem occured, try again later");
        }

        FormSaving abc;
        using (Stream loadstream = new FileStream(loadpath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
            abc = (FormSaving)serializer.Deserialize(loadstream);

        }

        MajorversionresultLabel.Content = abc.Majorversion;
    }
```

When i press the SaveButton, my label.content is saved into an xml file. However when i press the load button to load this xml file, i get the error "There is an error in XML document (0, 0)". I went to open my xml file after pressing the load button, it becomes blank and everything got erased. Can anyone help me fix this load button error?

Comment: The document did not become blank.  It was blank to begin with.  That's the error that is produced by opening a blank document.

Answer (score 2):

ok solved,

```
using (Stream loadstream = new FileStream(loadpath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FormSaving));
            abc = (FormSaving)serializer.Deserialize(loadstream);

        }
```

should have been FileMode.Open instead of FileMode.Create