# deserializing xml doc to a list of key value pairs

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to deserialize a list of key value pairs that represent a list of high scores and initials. I keep getting an error when I try to deserialize the XML document: `There is an error in XML document (0, 0).`

I am deserializing my XML document as below:

```
GameHighScore highScoreHelper = new GameHighScore();

XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameHighScore));
highScoreHelper = (GameHighScore)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);

for (int i = 0; i < highScoreHelper.highScoreList.Count; i++)
{
  highScore[i] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(highScoreHelper.highScoreList[i].Initials, highScoreHelper.highScoreList[i].Score);
}
```

Am I missing something in my helper class?

```
  [XmlRootAttribute("GameScore")]
  public class GameHighScore
  {
    [XmlArray("Scores")]
    [XmlArrayItem("HighScore")]
    public List<HighScoreStruct<string, int>> highScoreList;

    private HighScoreStruct<string, int> scoreListHelper;

    [Obfuscation(Exclude = true)]
    public struct HighScoreStruct<K, V>
    {
      [XmlElement("Initials")]
      public K Initials
      { get; set; }

      [XmlElement("Score")]
      public V Score
      { get; set; }

      public HighScoreStruct(K initials, V score) : this() 
      {
        Initials = initials;
        Score = score;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The constructor instanstiates the highscore list and 
    /// the high score struct.
    /// </summary>
    public GameHighScore()
    {
      highScoreList = new List<HighScoreStruct<string, int>>();
      scoreListHelper = new HighScoreStruct<string, int>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method creates the list of scores to be stored to the disk.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="scoreList"></param>
    public void CreateGameHighScore(List<KeyValuePair<string, int>> scoreList)
    {

      for (int i = 0; i < scoreList.Count; i++)
      {
        scoreListHelper = new HighScoreStruct<string, int>(scoreList[i].Key, scoreList[i].Value);
        highScoreList.Add(scoreListHelper);
      }
    }
  }
```

Generated XML document

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GameScore xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Scores>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>ZZZ</Initials>
      <Score>53125</Score>
    </HighScore>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>AAA</Initials>
      <Score>50000</Score>
    </HighScore>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>AAA</Initials>
      <Score>45000</Score>
    </HighScore>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>AAA</Initials>
      <Score>40000</Score>
    </HighScore>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>AAA</Initials>
      <Score>35000</Score>
    </HighScore>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>AAA</Initials>
      <Score>30000</Score>
    </HighScore>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>AAA</Initials>
      <Score>25000</Score>
    </HighScore>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>AAA</Initials>
      <Score>20000</Score>
    </HighScore>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>AAA</Initials>
      <Score>15000</Score>
    </HighScore>
    <HighScore>
      <Initials>AAA</Initials>
      <Score>10000</Score>
    </HighScore>
  </Scores>
</GameScore>
```

**EDIT**

The above XML document was generated by serializing my helper class.

The `stream` is gotten from below from Nick Gravelyn's EasyStorage Library:

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads a file.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="containerName">The name of the container from which to load the file.</param>
/// <param name="fileName">The file to load.</param>
/// <param name="loadAction">The load action to perform.</param>
public void Load(string containerName, string fileName, FileAction loadAction)
{
  VerifyIsReady();

  // lock on the storage device so that only one storage operation can occur at a time
  lock (storageDevice)
  {
    // open a container
using (StorageContainer currentContainer = OpenContainer(containerName))
{
      // attempt the load
  using (var stream = currentContainer.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open))
  {
    loadAction(stream);
  }
}
  }
}
```

My full Load Method is below:
Note: The save device is just an instance of my EasyStorage save device.

```
public static void Load()
{
  if (Global.SaveDevice.IsReady)
  {
    if (Global.SaveDevice.FileExists(Global.containerName, Global.filename_highscores_xml))
    {
      Global.SaveDevice.Load(
        Global.containerName,
        Global.filename_highscores_xml,
        stream =>
        {
          try
          {
            //stream.Position = 0;
            GameHighScore highScoreHelper = new GameHighScore();

            XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameHighScore));
            highScoreHelper = (GameHighScore)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);

            for (int i = 0; i < highScoreHelper.highScoreList.Count; i++)
            {
              highScore[i] = new KeyValuePair<string, int>(highScoreHelper.highScoreList[i].Initials, highScoreHelper.highScoreList[i].Score);
            }
          }
          catch (Exception e)
          {
            //if (!Global.SaveDevice.IsBusy && Global.SaveDevice.IsReady)
            //  Global.SaveDevice.DeleteAsync(Global.containerName, Global.filename_highscores_xml);
            //Save();
            Logger.LogError("Score.Load", e);
          }
        });
    }
    else
    {
      Save();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried just XML searlizing an instance of your helper?

Comment: The above XML file was serialized from an instance of my helper

Comment: And it errors reading it back in?

Comment: Yes I get the error stated in my question `There is an error in XML document (0, 0).`

Comment: try to read the inner exception

Comment: How do you read the inner exception?

Comment: Maybe the error is that the file it's saved as UTF8 With BOM, I use notepad++ to check the format of the text and changed to UTF8 without BOM, test if it's that the error of Xml document (0,0)

Comment: if you add a `try{} catch(Exception e){ ..e.InnerException.. }`. If I'm not mistaking the more detailed reason is stored in the inner exception.

Comment: @jjchiw is on to something, you should make sure that your reading and writing streams are using the same encoding.

Comment: could you also show the creation of `stream`?

Comment: Would you consider using the default Microsoft method of [Saving Data to a Save Game File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203924.aspx)

Comment: Looking more closely at the Easy storage library and comparing it to your link, that is exactly what he does in the library for saving and loading files, minus the XML serialization part that is mentioned in the link.

Comment: Have you tried just writing `stream` out to a file and comparing it to your serialized object?

Comment: The stream is exactly the same as my serialized object.

Comment: @Joshua Drake. It actually ended up being that I was doing too much processing during my save/load and because of that, when the game was closed, it never got around to saving the xml document: it was blank. So, when the xml file was loaded it threw the above error, which was "cannot find root node" for the inner exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There is an error in XML document](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/xmlandnetfx/thread/f5a5ff54-3743-400c-b14d-92dae95f3605)... states that

> After you have written to the stream it is positioned at the end... If you then try to read from that same stream there is no root element to be found... you need to reposition the stream...

Or possibly this SO question [Error during deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099476/there-is-an-error-in-xml-document-0-0-during-deserialization).

> should have been FileMode.Open instead of FileMode.Create

Comment: Wouldn't the stream be at the beginning if I load the XML document when my program starts up? If I haven't written to it yet?

Comment: @NexAddo it should be.  How are you loading it?

Comment: I'm loading it from my splash screen at the start of the program as stated above in the beginning of my question.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. I am currently using the EasyStorage library for XNA to Save and load my data to the disk. I will edit my post with the load method from the library

Comment: Not knowing how EasyStorage works, and finding their documentation lacking, have you tried explicitly setting the stream position to the beginning?

Comment: I still have the issue after setting the stream position to zero.

Answer (score 1):

I just used the code that you posted an it worked

```
GameHighScore highScoreHelper = new GameHighScore();

using (var stream = new FileStream("GameScore.xml", FileMode.Open))
{
    XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(GameHighScore));
    highScoreHelper = (GameHighScore)deserializer.Deserialize(stream);

    for (int i = 0; i < highScoreHelper.highScoreList.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(highScoreHelper.highScoreList[i].Initials, highScoreHelper.highScoreList[i].Score));
    }
}
```

BTW. The encoding of the file is UTF-8, VS just do that

Answer (score 0):

Try using LINQ to populate the dictionary:

```
//initialize the dictionary
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

//populate the dictionary with the xml document
doc.Descendants("HighScore")
    .Select(x => dict[x.Element("Initials").Value] = x.Element("Score").Value);
```

Comment: He's asking about a specific error when trying to deserialize the document.